# Correlation of random variables after multiplication by a constant

Tags: calculus, probability, statistics, correlation

Why is the following true for the covariance $cov(X, Y)$ and variances $Var(X)$, $Var(Y)$ of two rvs $X$ and $Y$:
$$
\frac{Cov(c X, Y)}{\sqrt{Var(c X) Var(Y)}} = \frac{c Cov(X, Y)}{\sqrt{c^2 Var(X) Var(Y)}} = \frac{Cov(X, Y)}{\sqrt{Var(X) Var(Y)}}
$$
I cannot see how the $c^2$ within the square root can disappear just because we have $c$ as a factor in the numerator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall that $\sqrt{ab} = \sqrt{a}\sqrt{b}$. Then,

$$\frac{c Cov(X, Y)}{\sqrt{c^2 Var(X) Var(Y)}} = \frac{c Cov(X, Y)}{\sqrt{c^2} \sqrt{ Var(X) Var(Y)}}= \frac{c Cov(X, Y)}{|c|\sqrt{Var(X) Var(Y)}} = \mathrm{sgn}(c)\frac{Cov(X, Y)}{\sqrt{ Var(X) Var(Y)}}$$

Comment: But $\sqrt{a b} = \sqrt{a} \sqrt{b}$ is not true? For example with $a=3$ and $b=3$?

Comment: @sostack Yes it is. $\sqrt{3 \times 3} = \sqrt{9} = 3$. Also, $\sqrt{3} \times \sqrt{3} = \sqrt{3}^2 = 3$.

Comment: @sostack Please see: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1025551/sqrtab-sqrta-sqrtb

Comment: Ah yea ofc. Sorry. Thank you so much for the answer! I appreciate your time :)